# Count duplicates between 2 lists

Tags: python, list, loops

```
a = [1, 2, 9, 5, 1]
b = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
```

I want to count the number of duplicates between the two lists. So using the above, I want to return a count of 2 because 9 and 5 are common to both lists.

I tried something like this but it didn't quite work.

```
def filter_(x, y):
    count = 0
    for num in y:
        if num in x:
            count += 1
            return count
```

Comment: Notice that once it works (dedent the `return` twice), it has `O(n * m)` complexit, i.e. scales pretty horribly.

Comment: @delnan thanks for the tip. so using intersection scales better.

Comment: Yes. You can actually do even better, but that requires more than one line of code (the idea is that you only need a set of the first list, then iterate over the second and keep the items that are in the set - saves creating a second set).

Comment: `a` contains `1` twice, if `b` contained `1` also, should the count be incremented by `1` or `2`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Shorter way and better:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 9, 5, 1]
>>> b = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
>>> len(set(a) & set(b))     # & is intersection - elements common to both
2
```

Why your code doesn't work:

```
>>> def filter_(x, y):
...     count = 0
...     for num in y:
...             if num in x:
...                     count += 1
...     return count
... 
>>> filter_(a, b)
2
```

Your `return count` was inside the for loop and it returned without execution being complete.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`set.intersection`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection):

```
>>> set(a).intersection(set(b)) # or just: set(a).intersection(b)
set([9, 5])
```

Or, for the length of the intersection:

```
>>> len(set(a).intersection(set(b)))
2
```

Or, more concise:

```
>>> len(set(a) & set(b))
2
```

Comment: I dont want 9,5. I want a count of 2.

Comment: It is not necessary to explicitly make a set from list b, the set intersection method supports lists as inputs.

Answer (score 8):

If you wish to count multiplicitous entries, the set-based solutions will fail; you will need something like

```
from collections import Counter

def numDups(a, b):
    if len(a)>len(b):
        a,b = b,a

    a_count = Counter(a)
    b_count = Counter(b)

    return sum(min(b_count[ak], av) for ak,av in a_count.iteritems())
```

then

```
numDups([1,1,2,3], [1,1,1,1,1])
```

returns 2. The running time on this scales as O(n+m).

Also, your initial solution

```
for num in y:
    if num in x:
        count += 1
```

is wrong - applied to [1,2,3,3] and [1,1,1,1,1,3], your code will return either 3 or 6, *neither* of which is correct (answer should be 2).

Comment: this solution is better because it counts the duplicates too, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Convert them to `set`s and count the intersection.

```
 len(set(a).intersection(set(b)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution also accounts for duplicate elements in the list:

```python
from collections import Counter

def number_of_duplicates(list_a, list_b):
    count_a = Counter(list_a)
    count_b = Counter(list_b)

    common_keys = set(count_a.keys()).intersection(count_b.keys())
    return sum(min(count_a[key], count_b[key]) for key in common_keys)
```

Then `number_of_duplicates([1, 2, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2, 4])` results in the expected `3`.

---

Note that @Hugh Bothwell also provided a similar solution, but it sometimes throws `KeyError` if an element is only contained in the shorter list.